# Single value vs Array in GraphQL Enum input types

Tags: graphql

How do you define an input type that either accepts a single enum value or an array of values in GraphQL?

According to [GitHub GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/),

```
{
  securityVulnerabilities(first: 3, ecosystem: RUBYGEMS) {
    nodes {
      advisory {
        description
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I think array can be good because user can search across ecosystem.

```
{
  securityVulnerabilities(first: 3, ecosystem: [RUBYGEMS, NPM]) {
    nodes {
      advisory {
        description
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: here is the good read https://graphql.org/learn/schema/

Comment: Are you asking how to pass an array of enum values, instead of a single enum value, as an argument to an existing endpoint, like Github's?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by defining the input value as an array `[]` of your defined `Enum`, something like:

```
enum MyEnum {
  RUBYGEMS
  NPM
}

type Query {
  securityVulnerabilities(ecosystem: [MyEnum!]): MyReturnObject
}
```

And then you can query it like:

```
{
  securityVulnerabilities(ecosystem: [RUBYGEMS, NPM]) {
    ....
  }
}
```

And it works with both an array or a single value:

```
{
  securityVulnerabilities(ecosystem: RUBYGEMS) {
    ....
  }
}
```

The [GraphQL spec](https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Type-System.List) explains the following:

> If the value passed as an input to a list type is *not* a list and not
> the **null** value, then the result of input coercion is a list of size
> one [...]

Comment: I edited in some clarification that it works for both use-case (array _and_ a single value) and cited the spec to explain that it's intended. If you feel that this edit is too big or goes against your initial intent, please feel free to rollback.